# Confirming the source of a pdf file

Tags: pdf

Many companies allow custoners obtain their utility bills in PDF format, direct from their account. These may be used to support 'proving identity' with other organisations.

Is it possible to confirm that such a pdf file which is offered as 'proof of address' did actually emanate from the utility provider, and also that the file was not edited?

Comment: Welcome aboard. Great question (+1). It is on topic here, but you may also want to be aware of our [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Answer (score 1):

PDF files may embed a *digital signature*, see [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/validating-digital-signatures.html), which can be validated at the receiver. It's for determining the originator, and to ascertain the PDF file has not been tampered with.